# Find the no. of edges of a graph G.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Consider an ***undirected graph G*** where ***self-loops are not allowed***. The vertex set of G is  {(i,j):1≤ i ≤12 , 1≤ j ≤12}.***There is an edge*** between (ܽa,b) and (ܿc,d) ***if |ܽa−ܿc| ≤1*** and ***|ܾb−݀d| ≤1***. 
What is the ***number of edges*** in this graph G ?

Comment: I get $264$ but I'm not sure if that's right. What do you get?

Comment: The correct answer is 506.

Comment: Oh, right. Picture an $11\times11$ chessboard, the corners of the square of the chessboard are the nodes of your graph. There are $12\cdot11=132$ horizontal edges, the same number of vertical edges, and $2\cdot11^2=242$ diagonal edges (two in each square of the chessboard), for a total of $132+132+242=506$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you lay this out on a $12\times 12$ grid (think the squares of a $12\times 12$ chess board, for instance), then every vertex has an edge to its $8$ (or $5$ or $3$) neighbours.

There are $10\cdot 10$ vertices with $8$ neighbours (any vertex not along an edge), $4\cdot 10$ vertices with $5$ neighbours (any vertex along an edge but not in a corner) and $4$ vertices with $3$ neighbours (the corner vertices). Adding up, that's $100\cdot 8 + 40 \cdot 5 + 4\cdot 3 = 800 + 200 + 12 = 1012$ edges. Now, naturally, we've counted each edge twice (once for each of the two vertices it connects), so the number of edges is half of this, or $506$.

Comment: 506 is the correct answer.Thank you so much Arthur.